# What is the difference between pure ASCII based games and SMFL games? What is SMFL exactly?

Tags: 2d, ascii, game-engine

What is SMFL exactly? I mean do I have to use something like SMFL to create 2D games always, if I do not want to use game engines like Unity? What are my options? Why isn't just using ASCII not enough?

Answer (score 0):

> What is SMFL exactly?

It's library that packs up all the inconvenient tasks of creating a window, setting up a graphics context for it, loading assets, connecting to input devices (mouse, keyboard, joysticks, game controllers), talking to the audio hardware etc.…

… in SFML all of this is wrapped up in a nice, coherent library.

> I mean do I have to use something like SMFL to create 2D games always

No, you can write everything from scratch, directly accessing the operating system's APIs. However this is a metric frackton of work, and you usually do that only if, and only if you're programming a fully blown, retargetable application framework or game engine.

> if I do not want to use game engines like Unity?

If you have to ask those questions, using a game engine like Unity or Godot is highly recommended. The amount of work to draw anything artistic to the screen and have nice sound come from the speakers is large enough without using a framework, or full blown engine. Doing it from scratch adds a few orders of magnitude of complexity.

> Why isn't just using ASCII not enough?

Because ASCII is just a character set. You at least also need a terminal. But you normally don't control the font used be the terminal, control sequences may vary. Sure ASCII art can look fine. But usually using SFML or SDL or similar to open a graphics window and drawing to it actually less work, than drawing nice looking ASCII art to a terminal.